# como eliminar los numeros del de FizzBuzz

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo el ejercicio de FizzBuzz, consiste en alistar una serie de numeros del 1 al 100 y que los numeros divisibles de 3 se muestre la palabra Fizz y si son mod de 5 la palabra buzz y si el numero es mod de ambos FizzBuzz, la cosa es que me salen las palabras acompa;adas del numero por ejemplo "Fizz3" Buzz5 y asi, ya estube probando y no logro poder eliminar esos numeros

```
var numeros = 100;
var divisible = false;
for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (esDivisible(i,3))
    {
        document.write("Fizz");
    }
    if(esDivisible(i,5))
    {
        document.write("Buzz");
    }
    if(!esDivisible(i,3) && !esDivisible(i,5));
     {
        document.write(i);
    }
        document.write("<br />");
}

function esDivisible(num, divisor)
{
    if(num % divisor == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Saludos. la sentencia **if(!esDivisible(i,3) && !esDivisible(i,5));** estás terminándola por el **;** que le pones por tanto el **{ document.write(i); }** que le tienes debajo no es parte de esa condición. Elimina el **;** antes mencionado.

Comment: Saludos, creo de berías intentar hacer le ejercicio usando una manera más sencilla. Usando If, else if, así verías como funciona. Si estás empezando hacer el ejercicio con una función, quizá te complica un poco.
Intenta hacerlo con una lógica más sencilla, resolviendo cada parte como un pequeño problema, así lo resolverás más fácil. Un Saludo